# ¿Cómo retorno una lista con rango de dos fechas con hql?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, hql

He creado una *inteface* de tipo *String* para la consulta de fechas de una demanda.

```
List<Demand> findAllDemandsBydates(String starDate, String endDate) throws ParseException;
```

Acá es donde implemento mi código y digo que es un *string* y le doy un *date format* para castear y este es mi forma como hago esta consulta:

```
@SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "unused" })
@Override
public List<Demand> findAllDemandsBydates(String starDate, String endDate) throws ParseException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    
        Date sDate = format.parse(starDate);
        Date  enDate = format.parse(endDate);

    
    
    return entityManager
            .createQuery("FROM Demand AS c WHERE c.id BETWEEN :requesteddate AND :agreeddate ")
            .setParameter("requesteddate", starDate).setParameter("agreeddate", endDate).getResultList();
}
```

En el código de mi controlador verifico si la lista esta vacía oh no para que me devuelva no contiene o si contiene un listado dentro de esas fechas.

```
@CrossOrigin("http://localhost:8080")
@ApiOperation("obtencion de demandas por fechas ")
@GetMapping("demandsbydates/{starDate}/{endDate}")
public ResponseEntity<List<Demand>> 
demandsbydates
(
        @PathVariable("starDate")String starDate ,
        @PathVariable("endDate") String endDate
) throws ParseException {
    List<Demand> list = userService.findAllDemandsBydates(starDate, endDate);

    if (list.isEmpty()) {
        return new ResponseEntity<List<Demand>>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
        // You many decide to return HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND
    }
    return new ResponseEntity<List<Demand>>(list, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Las fechas que van de inicio a fin son para consultarlas y darme una guía de donde voy  hasta donde termino.

Acá le presento data de mi base de datos que tengo para el rango de fechas que quiero consultar.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Así es como ingreso los parámetros en mi swagger para consultarlos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y por ultimo así es como tengo mi clase entidad.

```
        @Entity
    @Table(name = "demand")
    public class Demand {
    
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        private int id;
    
        @Column(name = "comentary", length = 500)
        private String comments;
    
        @Column(name = "description", length = 300)
        private String descriptions;
    
        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name = "id_responsible", referencedColumnName = "id")
        private Person persons;
    
        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name = "id_demand_state", referencedColumnName = "id")
        private DemandState demandstate;
    
        @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
        @Column(name = "register_at")
        @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss")
        @CreatedDate
        private Date registerat;
    
        @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
        @Column(name = "requested_date")
        private Date requesteddate;
    
        @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
        @Column(name = "agreed_date")
        private Date agreeddate;}
    
//getters and Setters
```

En resumen a todo no puedo obtener la consulta por que me sale *no content* y lo cual cuando quiero ver los logs  no me sale nada.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que pasa es que la consulta está comprobando si el `id` es el que se encuentra entre el rango de fechas `c.id BETWEEN :requesteddate AND :agreeddate`. Debes primero definir lo que deseas obtener para determinar el criterio de búsqueda. Por ejemplo, si lo que deseas es conocer aquellas demandas cuya fecha de solicitud está entre un rago definido por el usuario, tu consulta debería lucir así:

```
FROM Demand AS c WHERE c.requesteddate BETWEEN :requesteddate AND :agreeddate
```

Pero lo primero es definir cual sería el criterio y en base a eso comprar el atributo correcto de la entidad contra los datos que brinda el usuario desde la interfaz.

Comment: muchas gracias por su tiempo caballero pero me puede pasar un ejemplo o algo para saber como  haria esa criteria ? u.u

Comment: Se lo acabo de poner en la respuesta. Cuál atributo de su entidad es el que intenta comprobar si está entre el rango de fechas que envía el usuario "requesteddate" o "agreeddate"??

Comment: ah no si gracias caballero estaba haciendo mal la consulta , muchas gracias :)